# Why my terminal screen crashes?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, fonts, crash

Sometimes my system gets freezed, after that my icons looks crashed and the terminal fonts are also crashed [image]
Whenever I restart it looks normal, how to fix this?

Comment: looks like a graphics card/driver issue to me

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes my system gets freezed

You needs to figure out what's triggered the freeze,
try `tail /var/log/dmesg` or `journalctl -f` get ERR logs

> how to fix this?

You can try restart Xserver, instead of power cycle your machine.
Using keyboard combination `ctrl+art+backspace`
or using GUI implements
or `killall X` (you ought to start Xserver at tty on your own)